# Check if given information is genuine

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-classification

I want to build an algorithm which can verify a piece of content against ground truth and output whether the piece of content is providing genuine information or is fake.

I'm working on a stock trading platform and we use *influencer* marketing. Need to monitor whether the *influencers* are providing the correct information in their posts.

What would be the approach of building such a model?

What algorithms would be applicable?

Comment: Do you want to verify they are using the correct information you provide them with, or generally if the information they provide to their followers is correct according to the internet?

Comment: based on the information we provide them.